# Crimp and wire connection

Tags: crimp

I am using 22 AWG wire. The crimp fits 22-26 AWG.

I tried very hard to shove the wires inside the head of the crimp, to no avail. The picture below shows how my wires stop at the "crimped area" of the crimp.

[image]

Is it necessary to shove the wire all the way in when crimping?

Comment: I think you have inserted the wire the correct amount. It is not supposed to go farther. The remainder of the crimp is for making contact with the mating pin or whatever. But it is hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: @Aaron's answer is correct. The picture is of an uncrimped connector (the triangular flanges on the left and the rectangular flanges in the middle, they're what should be crimped).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crimps datasheet should describe the diameter of accepted insulation and the length of uninsulated wire should be exposed for a proper crimp.

The pokey triangle section crimps onto the insulation to hold it in place. The u shaped section where your wire is, is the part that crimps for mechanical and electrical connection to the wire and crimp.

The section you are trying to shove the wire into, is not supposed to have wire in it. You stripped the wire too long for the crimp, likely by a mm or so. That section will make a mechanical connection to a mating pin.

Your problem is almost this. Your insulation doesn't extend into the wire crimp but the wire does extend into the terminal.
[image]
<sub>(source: [molex.com](https://www.molex.com/tnotes/d7.gif))</sub>

Here is a guide by Molex for proper crimping. https://www.molex.com/tnotes/crimp.html

Comment: **The pokey triangle section [...]** *--the datasheet* (I don't have a better name for it, and this is a good answer. But this make me laugh)

Comment: Thanks! The pictures are really nice:)

Comment: This type of stuff becomes noticable after several thousand crimps and can have very subtle edge effects beyond crimp reliability. One thing that happens is a too long strand gets bent 90degrees and just barely touched/scratches the interior of the crimp under manipulation. If you have a basic resistive sensor at the other side of this (e.g. thermistor) it can appear like old fashioned record needle scratches on the recorded measurement when you jiggle the wires.

Comment: @z4 Molex calls it the insulation crimp.  But not all insulation crimps are pokey.

Comment: I notice that in this document (https://engineering3.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/E3-Crimping-Molex-Connectors.pdf) it is called the insulation layer crimp zone. Insulation crimp are the  keywords:)

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the wrong area to crimp.  It should be the area I've marked in the red box:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood the question. To the OP: is this picture showing the wire and crimp BEFORE you crimp it, or after? I agree with Aaron that the area in red is where you are supposed to crimp. The two prongs on the left are supposed to crimp the insulation, and the part on the right crimps the bare wire. To the right of the red box is the part that goes in the plastic housing and mates with the other connector or header.

Comment: @mkeith You might be right too, now that I've read your comments.  Only the OP can disambiguate at this point.

Comment: @mkeith it is BEFORE I crimp it. Thanks for the detailed explanation!